# Badges based on acceptance might not work if the account of the asker's account is closed

Tags: support, badges

Hi,

I had an answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) on SO that just went past the threshold for a badge based on an answer being accepted (in this case a 'guru').  The answer was accepted some time ago, and the asker appears to have subsequently closed their account.  The badge doesn't appear to have happened.

The question is (a): is this a bug caused by the original asker's account being closed, (b) functioning as designed or (c) something else?

**Edit** For specifics:

The answers to the questions that are accepted with 40 upvotes are:

- [Best language for safety-critical software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243387/best-language-for-safety-critical-software/243573#243573)
- [Python: Random is barely random at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145510/python-random-is-barely-random-at-all/2145551#2145551)
- [Application (Not a Markup Language) for Producing a User Manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371654/application-not-a-markup-language-for-producing-a-user-manual/372017#372017)
- [Why use Ruby instead of Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/556411#556411)
- [What do ‘real’, ‘user’ and ‘sys’ mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/556411#556411)

... With 4 'guru' badges on the account.  As far as I am aware none of the questions have been closed and migrated anywhere else.

On serverfault I have one accepted answer with 40 upvotes and a single 'guru' badge on the account:

- [What is good about the BSDs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5267/what-is-good-about-the-bsds/5352#5352)

This question was originally asked on SF and hasn't been migrated, so I don't think the problem is one of migrating questions between sites.

Comment: MAy have been the fact that it was CW?

Comment: I dont' think so - I have other guru badges on answers that are CW.  Also, I don't think CW mode affects this badge - I certainly can't see anything documented that states or implies that to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't "down" one guru badge? Remember that migrated and deleted questions don't remove the associated badges -- you just won't earn the next few until the badge counts actually match the correct, remaining posts in the system.

edit: looks one one just barely made the threshold -- have you waited at least 24 hours? Some of the badges are awarded infrequently, for the ones that tend to happen infrequently, to reduce load on the database.

It's also *possible* the deletion of the user can affect this, I have seen subtle side-effecty things from that before. I'll check tomorrow

Comment: As far as I can see none of the questions have been deleted or migrated.  They're certainly not marked as such and I can see them all regardless of whether I'm logged in or out of the site.  I've edited the question to add a list of specific accepted answers with 40 upvotes.

Comment: Given that I can't see any that have been deleted (unless http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/ has actually been scheduled for termination) is it possibly intentional behaviour that badges are not generated on answers by users who subsequently deleted their account (i.e. b - functioning as designed).

Comment: In answer to the first edit, the answer got to 40 upvotes a week or two ago, and I posted this a few days after it did when I noticed that it hadn't generated a guru badge.  The original account that had posted the question had been deleted (presumably after the owner accepted the answer); I posted this as a bug as it has the feel of of an odd corner case where a bug like this might lurk.

Comment: Note that the last one to make the threshold was the one about real, user and sys times - the one about ruby with 41 upvotes went past the threshold ages ago.